# Defining variables in org mode using tables

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I often want to define a whole bunch of variables at the top of an org file. In some cases I think it would be really nice to define all the variables in a table. So far, the best solution I've come up with is this:

```
#+NAME: variables
| Variable | Value      | Description |
|----------+------------+-------------|
| user1    | alice      | Manager     |
| user2    | bob        | Developer   |

#+NAME: lookup
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var data=variables var="a var name"
  (nth 1 (assoc var data))
#+end_src

#+begin_src sh :var user=lookup(var="user1")
 echo $user
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: alice
```

That works, but the syntax `:var user=lookup(var="user1")` is verbose, and it gets tiresome to call `lookup` in *every* `:var` header argument. I'm wondering if there is a way to register each variable and value in the table as though they were defined like this:

```
#+NAME: user1
: alice

#+NAME: user2
: bob
```

That way, you could write source blocks with simple and familiar
`:var` header arguments, like:

```
#+begin_src sh :var user=user1
  echo $user
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: alice
```

So I guess my question is: is there a way to "register" the variables/values in the `variables` table in such a way that would let me use them like `:var user=user1`?

Or even just an alternative way to do something similar that you find works for you?

**EDIT**: I perused the org source code a bit; I don't see any super easy way to do this. Maybe the best idea would be to introduce a new header argument, like `#+begin_src :tblvar user=user1`, which resolves variables defined in a table.

Answer (score 4):

I don't find this any easier than what you have already shown, but here are some different approaches that use advanced features (https://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-features.html) of naming fields in tables. You have to put the $ in the first column to name these constants. Getting these into your variable is a little verbose, but explicit at least. The `org-table-get-remote-range` function returns a string of the value in parentheses, so I use read to turn it into lisp, then a car in the front to get the element from the list.

```
#+NAME: variables
|   | Value       | Description |
|---+-------------+-------------|
| $ | user1=alice | Manager     |
|---+-------------+-------------|
| $ | user2=bob   | Developer   |

#+begin_src sh :var user=(car (read (org-table-get-remote-range "variables" "$user2")))
 echo $user
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: bob
```

If having extra functions is on the table, you might do something like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(defmacro ot (name field)
  `(car (read (org-table-get-remote-range ,(symbol-name name) , (symbol-name field)))))
#+END_SRC
```

so that it is a little shorter:

```
#+begin_src sh :var user=(ot variables $user2))
 echo $user
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: bob
```

The final version, which may not be a good idea is to load the variables in the table to a local variable space in the buffer. To do this, you have to get the variables by going to the table, analyzing it and then using setq-local to add them to the local space.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(defun org-goto-named-table (name)
  (let ((pos (catch 'pos
           (cl-loop for table in  (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'table 'identity)
            do
            (when (string= name (org-element-property :name table))
              (throw 'pos (org-element-property :contents-begin table)))))))
    (when pos (goto-char pos))))



(defun org-load-local-table-variables (name)
  (save-excursion
    (org-goto-named-table name)
    (org-table-analyze)
    (cl-loop for (name . value) in org-table-local-parameters
         do (eval `(setq-local ,(intern name) value)))
    org-table-local-parameters))
#+END_SRC
```

Then you need a src block to run the function that loads them:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(org-load-local-table-variables "variables") 
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: ((user2 . bob) (user1 . alice))
```

And finally, you can use `, notation to use those var-names in your src-blocks. I leave it to you to decide if these variables should be prefixed, e.g instead of user2, maybe variables-user2.

```
#+begin_src sh :var user=`,user2
echo $user
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: bob
```

You might also consider variations on this theme where instead of using setq-local, you use the returned results of the org-load-local-table-variables and do look up by alist, etc...

Comment: Amazing! I am learning a lot from this.

Answer (score 1):

I use `#+constants: variable=value` for this and then `(org-table-get-constant "variable")` to get the value for src blocks etc.  The advantage is that constants can be used directly in tables with `$variable`.

Comment: I am missing an example. Where do you use the lisp part? In a separate code block? `$variable`, do you use in a table? - I voted for the Q:, I would like also for the answer...

Comment: The lisp part can be used in src blocks to set variables, as in `:var myvar=(org-table-get-constant "variable")` on the `#+begin_src` line. In tables, the `$variable` can be used in any formula where you would use, e.g., a reference to an entry in the table such as `@3$5`.

Comment: Cool idea. It's definitely nice to be able to define several variables in one line using `#+CONSTANTS`.